# input fields associative array

Tags: javascript

Let's say, i have two input fields, their values: val1 and val2. (they are strings)

How do i convert them into associative array: {val1:val2} first value as key, second one as value??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't "convert" something to array. If you mean you want such array created using the values, David answer is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var foo = {};
foo[document.getElementById('an_input').value] = document.getElementById('another_input').value
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// get the key and the value
var key = document.getElementById('input1').value;
var val = document.getElementById('input2').value;

// and store 'em
var obj = {};     // need an empty object first, as you
obj[key] = val;   // can't store a property on a null value
```